# Azure app service recycle does it drain the queue

Tags: azure, azure-app-services

We have an issue where we can't use the arr affinity in an azure app service because it does not work behind a front door using a custom domain (the arr cookie has the wrong host on it for the browser to accept), this appears to be a limitation of app service and/or front door.

So we're looking at only using one instance of our app service per region, but we're now at risk of azure recycling our app whenever they want as we only have one node.

So the question is... in a recycle event does the app service drain its http queue of requests that are in flight before issuing the restart command? Or are all requests killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a Windows web service then it works the same as IIS, it will drain requests so long as they finish within 90 seconds.